# How to authenticate google cloud firestore using Curl and ID token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to use the curl command to authenticate Google Cloud Firestore database using an ID token. The ID token was generated using the custom firestore token. However when I do that I am getting different errors.

I have tried the following commands for authentication using the ID token but none of them are working:

```
>curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ID_TOKEN}" https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/Project-dev/databases/\(default\)/documents/properties

>curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ID_TOKEN}" https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/Project-dev/databases/\(default\)/documents/properties
```

The error message I am seeing is  :
    **"message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"**

Here is the structure of my database. Not sure if its a URL issue or how do I find the correct URL!
[image]

The firebase rules look this

Here is the rule  -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /pr/{prId}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if string(request.auth.token.prId)  == prId ;
    }   

    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if string(request.auth.uid) == userId;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the error or problem with those commands.  What are you expecting them to produce?

Comment: According to the error message, the Firestore security rules would be the first to check ...but without the structure of the Firestore and these rules, this question most likely cannot be answered.

Comment: I have updated the rules and attached the image which indicates the structure of database.